# Is it possible to get query params with Pydantic if param's name use special symbols?

Tags: python, schema, fastapi, pydantic

I'm handling this request in my code (Python3.9, FastAPI, Pydantic):

[https://myapi.com/api?params[A]=1&params[B]=2](https://myapi.com/api?params%5BA%5D=1&params%5BB%5D=2)

I tried to make following model:
[BaseModel for handling special get request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fbk6Y.png)
(for `fastapi.Query` and `pydantic.Field` is same)

I also set up aliases for it, but in swagger docs I see next field:
[Snap of the swagger docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Owe6x.png)

There are fields that are specified as `extra_data`

So, if I specify query params in parameters of my endpoint like this:

```
@app.get('/')
def my_handler(a: str = Query(None, alias="params[A]")):
     return None
```

Everything works fine. How can I fix it? I want to initialize my pydantic.BaseModel with speacial aliases using this way and avoid usage of query-params in

```
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    a = Field(alias="params[A]") 
    b = Field(alias="params[B]")
def my_handler(model: MyModel = Depends()):
    return model.dict()
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Ran into the same problem while trying to use an alias to query nested objects via mongodb... ("object_name.attribute")